# I want to make slick slider for product gallery in woocommerce archive, what do I do wrong?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, slick.js

It's displaying incorrectly. Slick with lightbox, but I tried to use it without it, so it isn't lightbox causing incorrect work. I want exactly coding, not plugins.

php part, where I display gallery

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', ' themename_loop_product_div_image_open', 5);
function themename_loop_product_div_image_open(){
?>
  <div class="wrap-loop-img-item">
    <?php 
    global $product;       
    
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    if ( ! empty( $attachment_ids ) ) {         
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {?><div class="slider-item"><?php 
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail' )?></div><?php ;
  }}else{
    $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->get_id() );
    $product_thub = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail'); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $product_thub;?>" alt="">      
      <?php 
  }
  ?>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', ' themename_loop_product_div_image_close', 30);
function  themename_loop_product_div_image_close(){  
  ?>
  </div>   
   <?php }
```

js-part

```
jQuery('.wrap-loop-img-item').each(function() {
  var slider = jQuery(this);
  slider.slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots:false,
  arrows: false,  
  driggable:false,
  swipe: false,
 swipeToSlide: false,
 touchMove: false,
});
var sLightbox = jQuery(this);
  sLightbox.slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
    itemSelector: '.img.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail.size-woocommerce_thumbnail',   
  });
});
```

Maybe you see where I make a mistake? Or maybe I don't know something about it, that I have to know.

Comment: I have an advice for you. Make a codepen and add HTML CSS and JS, whatever you have done until now, (reproducable example). Add it here. You will have a good chance of getting an answer. Its rather difficult to help by just looking, as you haven't even added the error message or exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: maybe it's a good idea. if it's a dynamic element, how to make it right - copy from the devtool html result of the gallery?

Comment: Yes. Copy HTML from Elements Tab. Put basic CSS and Add your JS the real issue. You will start to see some problems yourself once you start seperating them.